# mysql results ordering incorrectly using set FIELD and case

Tags: mysql

I've got the following variable and query.  For some reason, it is sorting the results in the wrong order.

```
$fieldlist = 'SMOOTH,EMBOSSED,AAR,EMBOSSED AAR';

$strap_query = $db1q->query("
SELECT id,name,tag,size,break,footage,coils_per_skid,core_size,grade,color,cost 
FROM Plastic_Strapping 
WHERE subcat=$subcat AND visibility='1' 
ORDER BY case when tag in ('$fieldlist') then 0 else 1 end, FIELD(tag,'$fieldlist'), sort_order ASC") 
or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($db1q));
```

**The order is *SUPPOSED TO BE***

1. SMOOTH
2. EMBOSSED
3. AAR
4. EMBOSSED AAR

**But instead, it is sorting them in the following *INCORRECT* order**

1. SMOOTH
2. AAR
3. EMBOSSED
4. EMBOSSED AAR

**Any idea why?**

is it because EMBOSSED AAR contains EMBOSSED? so its putting it after AAR?  If so, any idea how to fix that?

---

### Edit

Placing `'SMOOTH','EMBOSSED','AAR','EMBOSSED AAR'` in the `ORDER BY FIELD` section works; however, I'd still like to be able to edit this via a variable.  The following does NOT work.

```
$fieldlist = "'SMOOTH','EMBOSSED','AAR','EMBOSSED AAR'";

$strap_query = $db1q->query("SELECT id,name,tag,size,break,footage,coils_per_skid,core_size,grade,color,cost FROM Plastic_Strapping WHERE subcat=$subcat AND visibility='1' ORDER BY case when tag in ('$fieldlist') then 0 else 1 end, FIELD(tag, $fieldlist), sort_order ASC") or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($db1q));
```

throws this error

> **Unable to execute query. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SMOOTH','EMBOSSED','AAR','EMBOSSED AAR'') then 0
>   else 1 end, FIELD(tag, 'SMOOTH'' at line 1**

Comment: try `"SELECT id,name,tag,size,break,footage,coils_per_skid,core_size,grade,color,cost 
FROM Plastic_Strapping 
WHERE subcat=$subcat AND visibility='1' 
ORDER BY  FIELD( tag, 'SMOOTH','EMBOSSED','AAR','EMBOSSED AAR' )  "`

Comment: Does your query return other tags? If so, would you please post the full result? Because I think that the order of elements in `$fieldlist` does not affect the order using `Case`. It will put any element that is in the fieldlist before any other element, that's it..

Comment: the case part works because I'm using it in another section of the site.  In this particular query at this point in time, there are no other tags; however, not saying there wont be in the future.  But the case just puts thse tags first in the list, orders them by the field, and then places all other tags after and sorts them by sort_order

Comment: @Amani - that worked.  Now how do I put that into a variable so that I can just call the variable?  Check edit for code I tried that didn't work.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$fieldlist = 'SMOOTH,EMBOSSED,AAR,EMBOSSED AAR';

  $query = "SELECT id,name,tag,size,break,footage,coils_per_skid,core_size,grade,
      color,cost  FROM Plastic_Strapping WHERE subcat = $subcat AND visibility='1'
     ORDER BY FIELD( tag, '".implode("','",explode(',',$fieldlist))."' )";
```

#### Update

If your `$fieldlist` variable is like this:

```
$fieldlist = "'SMOOTH','EMBOSSED','AAR','EMBOSSED AAR'";
```

Your query would be like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id,name,tag,size,break,footage,coils_per_skid,core_size,grade,
           color,cost 
           FROM Plastic_Strapping WHERE subcat = $subcat AND visibility = '1' 
           ORDER BY case when tag in ($fieldlist) then 0 else 1 end, 
                    FIELD(tag, $fieldlist), sort_order ASC ";
```

Comment: error:   Unable to execute query. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''',''EMBOSSED'',''AAR'',''EMBOSSED AAR'' ), sort_order ASC' at line 1

Comment: you changed `$fieldlist` variable .. please see my update

Comment: oh whoops.  I changed it back. I checked BOTH options and both worked.  I like the second one because the query is a lot cleaner so I went with that one.  Thanks!

Comment: you can also avoid this `case when tag in ($fieldlist) then 0 else 1 end` so your query can be like this `SELECT .... ORDER BY  FIELD(tag, $fieldlist) ASC`. same results

Comment: Will that place results with other tags under the ones that are in the tag?  I attempted doing that in the past and it didn't sort correctly.  It put items that were not listed as value of "NULL" or "0" and they sorted incorrectly.  Some tag columns are empty, some are listed, and some are not listed.

Comment: Ah ok i see what you mean .. then keep it as it is.